# Content going off the page overlapping footer

Tags: php, html, css, footer

I'm having some issues where the content on my website is going off the end of the page.
{link removed} - Question answered
If you click the search button on the left hand side, you'll see what I mean. I can't seem to get my head around why this is happening. The coding is a bit messy at the moment, but will eventually clean it up. Any help given will be appreciated!

Comment: Looks fine on firefox, post some code where you think the problem is

Comment: If you click on the featured property picture, it overlaps the footer... I use firefox but it's not looking good for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set a height of 110px on the div with class `products_box`.

Remove that height and everything will be fixed.